# Scala : How to find types of values inside a scala nested collection

Tags: scala, collections, nested, scala-collections, instanceof

consider the following variables in scala :

```
val nestedCollection_1 = Array(
  "key_1" -> Map("key_11" -> "value_11"),
  "key_2" -> Map("key_22" -> "value_22"))

val nestedCollection_2 = Map(
  "key_3"-> ["key_33","value_33"],
  "key_4"-> ["key_44"->"value_44"])
```

Following are my questions :

1) I want to read the values of the variables `nestedCollection_1`, `nestedCollection_2` and ensure that the value of the variables are of the format

```
Array[Map[String, Map[String, String]]
```

and

```
Map[String, Array[String]]]
```

2) Is it possible to get the detailed type of a variable in scala? i.e. `nestedColelction_1.SOME_METHOD` should return `Array[Map[String, Map[String, String]]` as type of its values

Comment: There is something that doesn't sit right with me here. If you are the one creating "nestedCollection_1" it means you already made it to be `Array[Map[String, Map[String, String]]`, right? Are you reading the nestedCollection as a serialized object?

Comment: The "nestedCollection_1" here i have hard-coded for testing purpose . later i will be assigning "nestedCollection_1" with value by reading from file.
The answer given by Łukasz is what i was expecting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exacltly do you mean. Compiler can ensure type of any variable if you just annotate the type:

```
val nestedCollection_2: Map[String, List[String]] = Map(
  "key_3"-> List("key_33", "value_33"),
  "key_4"-> List("key_44", "value_44"))
```

You can see type of variable in scala repl when you define it, or using `Alt + =` in Intellij Idea.

```
scala> val nestedCollection_2 = Map(
     |   "key_3"-> List("key_33", "value_33"),
     |   "key_4"-> List("key_44", "value_44"))
nestedCollection_2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(key_3 -> List(key_33, value_33), key_4 -> List(key_44, value_44))
```

**Edit**

I think I get your question now. Here is how you can get type as String:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def typeAsString[A: TypeTag](elem: A) = {
  typeOf[A].toString
}
```

Test:

```
scala> typeAsString(nestedCollection_2)
res0: String = Map[String,scala.List[String]]
scala> typeAsString(nestedCollection_1)
res1: String = scala.Array[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])]
```

Comment: I read the input from a file and the expected format of the input is in another file. I need to ensure that the input read from the file matches the expected format that is defined in another file

Comment: You said you read values from variables, and now you say you read them from file. So how do you covert the string from file to a variable of unknown to you type? What is its format?

Comment: Sorry  for the confusion....input is stored directly in a variable and the expected format is stored in a file...I will read the expected format from file and check if the input variable matches with  expected format that I read from file

Comment: Awesome thanks :) the edited answer was what i was expecting :) :)